# (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender doesn't work in view that i set as contentview of mainmenu's window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsevent

I set a NSViewController's view as contentview of mainmenu's window,now how should i use - (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender ?

i use `<NSWindowDelegate>` in @interface and put `- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` on .m but doesn't work

Comment: Are you saying you're trying to make an NSViewController into the delegate for a window? That would be quite unusual. That would more typically be the window's controller (although it can be any object). Anyway, you need to set the `delegate` property of the window to point to its delegate object. Since `delegate` is also an outlet of NSWindow's, you can hook that up in IB. Or, you can do it in code.

Comment: i want when user close window (window that i set NSViewController's view as content of it).you mean that i use '[self.view.window setDelegate' in viewController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-(BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` only gets sent to the delegate of the window that will be sending the message. (if you're not crystal clear on what delegates are, they're kind of like the army commander that everybody reports to)

Here, in order to be able to use `-windowShouldClose:` in your `NSViewController`, you need to set the `NSViewController` as the window's `delegate`. There's two steps to this:

1. Make it possible for the 'NSViewController' to be the window
   delegate. Usually the window's delegate is the `NSWindowController`
   (it's named that for a reason), but if you want to make
   'NSViewController' the delegate you need to use the
   `<NSWindowDelegate>` protocol, which you've already done.
2. Actually set the view controller as the delegate. As Ken Thomases
   noted in his comment, you can do this in Interface Builder by
   dragging the window's `delegate` outlet and connecting it to your
   NSViewController. Or you could do it programmatically:
   `[self.view.window setDelegate:self]` as you mentioned should work.

Comment: I connect delegate of window in mainMenu.xib and before i set viewController's view as content view of window i do `[self.vControllerObject.view.window setDelegate:self];` and then i use `-(BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender` in view controller but doesn't work.

Comment: If you've already done it in Interface Builder you don't need to do it again in code. | Also, in code: What exactly do you want as the delegate? If you want the view controller as the delegate, and you're calling from your AppDelegate class, you want `[self.vControllerObject.view.window setDelegate:vControllerObject]`, or better yet, `[self.window setDelegate:vControllerObject]` if you have the window property that comes w/ the template.